# Will be vs will get

Tags: grammar

In a general conversation I want to tell my friend that, due to extreme temperature he may get sun burns if he goes to a certain place during summer. I am confused which of the below sentences is grammatically correct and more recommended.

1.You *will* burn if you go to Tanjore during this time.

2.You *will get* burned if you go to Tanjore during this time.

3.You *will be* burned if you go to Tanjore during this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We would often clarify that the burning is from the sun by saying

> sunburned

(in passing, note that **sunburned** and **sunburnt** are both used, the former being more common in the US and the latter more common in the UK)

> You will burn

Is not right, that has more of a feeling of being set on fire

> The sun will burn you

does convey the idea, but feels less idiomatic than

> You will be sunburned

I can't really say why, but as a native speaker I would instinctively use **get**

> You will get sunburned

I think it's possibly because the burn appears on the surface of the skin, after the exposure. After some time in the sum you realise that you have been burned, your skin has now turned red, the burn is something you "carry" with you have acquired a burn.